# Question that is just a BIG BLOCK OF CODE, in what way do I vote to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have recently come across quite a few questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13768147/561731) [now 10K only] where all I see is:

```
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

    <ol>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
       <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ol>

    <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

    <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

    <ul>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
       <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ul>

    <pre><code>
    #header h1 a { 
        display: block; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 80px; 
    }
    </code></pre>

<ul>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
</ul>
            <dl>
   <dt>Definition list</dt>
   <dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
   <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt>
   <dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
</dl>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
            <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Are we expected to go through stuff like that?

I have just been downvoting and voting to close as "too localized".
Is that the proper procedure?

<sub><sup>[gibberish code came from here](http://html-ipsum.com/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that people are freaking out over fake sandbox credentials on that question. OMG you're letting people login to a test that doesn't do anything!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Downvote, flag or vote to close as "Not A Real Question":

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

A question that only contains a block of code is too vague and incomplete.

Comment: Yes, "too localized" is more for when the problem *is* defined, but it's just not applicable to anyone but the OP. NaRQ is for when the problem just plain isn't defined, like in the example question.

Comment: @MikeB why does it necessarily have to be deleted?

Comment: @MikeB: Closing is not the same thing as deleting. A closed question can be improved and re-opened.

Comment: @MikeB I did not flag. I voted to close. **Big** difference.

Comment: @MikeB: Flagging to close as NaRQ is not the same thing as asking a moderator to delete it either. I updated my answer to clarify the verb 'flag'; it's 'flag or vote' (depending on your retputation).

Comment: @MartijnPieters The 'or' edit changes everything :)

Comment: @MikeB: Why does it? Flagging just asks a moderator to close the question. Flagging as NARQ does not mean it'll be deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The overlapping meanings is what confuses me. I have enough reputation to do everything you said but delete questions in every circumstance. If I find a question that falls under the criteria described by OP I don't see the point in performing 3 actions (downvote, close-vote, **and** flag). Downvote if the question has hope through edits, close-vote if its a duplicate or if it needs to be deleted in a timely-manner (low quality posts) and flag if I think it needs immediate deletion. I don't know why I'd downvote just to have the 2 reputation returned to me in a couple hrs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Flagging just asks a moderator to close the question. Flagging as NARQ does not mean it'll be deleted"* - So under what circumstance would I vote to close a question AND NOT flag it as well if they both result in the question being closed?

Comment: @MikeB: You rarely need to flag anything for immediate deletion. A NaRQ is usually not a candidate for immediate deleting. I included 'flag' as an option for those that do not have the reputation to vote instead.

Answer (score 7):

I personally would close as "not a real question"  but to each his own i suppose.

There are some code-heavy questions that actually have merit, but if you can't find the merit before you get knee-deep in code, than I'd say you're perfectly justified in voting to close.

You should never have to go through someone's code to figure out what the requirement is.  As much as new users like to tell you "the code explains it all"  it normally doesn't do so very clearly, and that kind of question is to be discouraged.

**oh**, and leave a constructive comment too.  You can at least give new users a chance to improve.

Comment: Another common problem is that the code might demonstrate their problem quite clearly, but also demonstrate half a dozen other significant problems so you wouldn't know which to address in an answer.